# SQL Aqua Data Studio average over date by customer

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, aqua-data-studio

I am trying to find the 3 day moving average for customers. Here is my attempt.

```
    SELECT
        CUSTOMER_ID, AUTH_DATE, 
        AVG(AMOUNT) OVER(PARTITION BY CUSTOMER_ID, AUTH_DATE ORDER BY AUTH_DATE RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '3 DAYS' PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS MA_3_DAY
    FROM CUTOMER_TABLE
    ;
```

I have also tried

```
auth_date - interval '3 days' PRECEDING
```

and

```
current row - interval '3 days' PRECEDING
```

and

```
3 PRECEDING
```

I'm pretty sure I've used this code in other environments but Aqua Data Studio (connected to redshift) gives me a "syntax error at or near 'interval'"

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can only have `ROW` or `Range` in a windows function, so make a cte with days as rows and use that as basis

Comment: this explain the system quite comprhensive https://learnsql.com/blog/sql-window-functions-rows-clause/